# show div tag in php statement

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am now working on a WordPress theme base with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, And I want to show a `<div>` tag when the `if` statement is true. Here is my code:

```
 <?php 
    $rows = get_field('classification');
    $sort = get_sub_field('sort');
    $row_count = count($rows);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)?>
    <?php if ( $i==1 || $i%5==0) { ?>
      <div class="bor"></div>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">
        <?php echo $sort; ?>
        <a id="browser"></a></h3>
       <div class="bor"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

or something like that

```
    <?php 
    $rows = get_field('classification');
    $fenlei = get_sub_field('fenlei');
    $row_count = count($rows);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)?>
    <?php if ( $i==1 || $i%5==0) { ?>
      echo '<div class="bor"></div>';
        echo '<h3 style="text-align:center">';
        <?php echo $fenlei; ?>
        echo '<a id="browser"></a></h3>';
       <div class="bor"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

But the content of the div tag doesn't show.
Any reply is appreciated！Thank you very much.

Comment: your code is lost.. where is it?

Comment: Sorry this my first post,I need sometime to get use to this system.

Comment: hmm, weird. in a plain php i think it should work. is there any error reported? also, have you checked on the page source (the html generated)?

Comment: Yes,I had checked the source code of the html.there are 6 lines of space there.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some of your echo statement are out php tags. use this:

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field('classification');
    $fenlei = get_sub_field('fenlei');
    $row_count = count($rows);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++){
       if ( $i==1 || $i%5==0) {
         echo "<div class='bor'></div>
               <h3 style='text-align:center'>".$fenlei."
               <a id='browser'></a></h3>
               <div class='bor'></div>";
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Anuja Agarwal for your code,now the div had been shown on the html page.

Comment: can you please accept and upvote it then. you know click on the checkmark on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to show the html in php, i suggest you use the below code.

```
    <?php 
    $rows = get_field('classification');
    $fenlei = get_sub_field('fenlei');
    $row_count = count($rows);
    for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++){
        if ( $i==1 || $i%5==0) { 
            echo '&gt;div class="bor"&lt;&gt;/div&lt;';
            echo '&gt;h3 style="text-align:center"&lt;';
            echo $fenlei;
            echo '&gt;a id="browser"&lt;&gt;/a&lt;&gt;/h3&lt;';
            echo '&gt;div class="bor"&lt;&gt;/div&lt;';
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using an ACF Pro Repeater field. in this case you need to use `the_row()` which will set the sub-field's correct content. look at this edited example from the [Docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/):

> ```
> <?php
> // check if the repeater field has rows of data
> if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):
>   // loop through the rows of data
>     while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();
>         // display a sub field value
>         the_sub_field('sub_field_name');
>     endwhile;
> endif;
>
> ?>
> ```

so, I think your code should look more like:

```
<?php 
    if(have_rows('classification')): 
    while (have_rows('classification') ) : the_row();
    // Your Code...
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

And, I've learned recently you need to count the rows outside the `while` loop. othewise it won't catch the rows amount.